# Show a different value from an input that what will be received as php

Tags: javascript, php, forms, input

I'd like to know if there is a way to show in an input of type text a different value than the one sent to PHP.

For example, let say you have :

`<input type="text" value="John">` that display, John.

Can I change the value to "Doe" for the user but keep it to "John" for PHP?

Can I achieve this using the difference between `$.attr('value')` and `$.val()`?

I ran a couple of tests and it seems that I will have to reverse it directly in my controller. Is there another solution?

Here is a little [jSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trwdwvbm/2/) to play with.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An odd request to be sure but...

You can't change the field's value and just do a simple form submission. The field will dutifully send whatever is in it. There's a few hackery ways around this tho

## Option 1 - Hidden fields

So make a field, `disable` it, and add a hidden field. Disabled fields are never successful, although the user will be unable to change the field value and many browsers will change the styling of the field automatically

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="John" disabled>
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Doe">
```

## Option 2 - Change the value on submit

As you mentioned, you can always change the value when the form is submitted. The below listener will capture the form submitt Using jQuery since you asked it that way

```
$("form").on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('input[name="name"]').val('Doe');
  $("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: I misread the question. This part: *"Can I change the value to "Doe" for the user but keep it to "John" for php."* - My bad. I "might" end up deleting my answer.

Comment: You might want to change one of the `name="name"` names as well. If you follow me

Answer (score 1):

**1. you shall add a variable name like**

```
<input type="text" name='John' value="Doe">
```

in PHP a `var_dump('John')` will result in `'Doe'`

but obviously this is not very clever way, especially in case you have more then one input field, so I suggest

**2. using an array like**

```
<input type="text" name='person[John]' value="Doe">
<input type="text" name='person[Fred]' value="Flintstone">
```

in PHP you can selectively test like

```
if( isset($_POST['person']['John']) ) {
   ... do something ...
}elseif( isset($_POST['person']['Fred']) ) {
   ... do something different...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to a (pure) PHP solution, sure you can.

Sidenote: It's best to have a serverside method (as a Plan-B), should the end-user disable Javascript.

Given the user will replace the "already shown" value in the input though.

The input needs to hold a name attribute in order for this method to work.

```
<?php 

if(!empty($_POST['name'])){

   echo $name = $_POST['name']; // Will echo what was replaced in the input

}

else{
 echo $name = $_POST['name']; // Will echo the value that was already set in the input
}

?>


<form method="post">

<input type="text" value="John" name="name">

<input type="submit">

</form>
```

Note: `echo $var = "something";` is valid syntax.

---

### Edit:

It's unclear as to what you want to achieve here. However you can use a hidden attribute and remove `value="John"` from the input.

The user will need to fill the input.

The following will only output "Doe" if the input was left blank, yet output both if it is filled.

```
<?php 

if(!empty($_POST['name'])){

   echo $name = $_POST['name'];

}

    else{
     echo $name = $_POST['name'];
    }


if(isset($_POST['hidden_name_value'])){

   echo $hidden = $_POST['hidden_name_value'];

}



?>


<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="name">

<input type="hidden" name="hidden_name_value" value="Doe">

<input type="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: *"Can I change the value to "Doe" for the user but keep it to "John" for php."* - I misread that part. I'll take a negative vote(s); I've broad shoulders.

Comment: Both answer were correct I tough of them before but wasn't sure if there was not a better way (quicker, safer, etc..) Anyway Thank you !

Comment: @Baldráni You're most welcome. I'm glad you got the solution that you needed, *cheers*.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a data-value attribute for the value you want to use in the PHP?

```
$("form").on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('input[name="name"]').val($(event).data('value'));
  $("form").submit();
});
```

Something like that?