# Making input tag display value and actual value(stored in value attribute) different?

Tags: javascript, html

For some functionality I want my actual value and display value be different. Is there any way through JS to do that?

One method is to take another input tag with same name/id but hidden.

Comment: What type of input tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a different value from an input that what will be received as php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227986/show-a-different-value-from-an-input-that-what-will-be-received-as-php)

Comment: @Quentin  input type is text

Comment: What's the point of letting the user type something into an input if you are going to ignore it and send a different value?

Comment: @quentin The input field is readonly in some scenarios and editable in another.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
The way I'd probably do it is attach some javascript before the submit and an event listener to the input if it's needed to facilitate the property state, as in if you want the property to be custom, not 'value' you need an event listener on 'change' that will keep your custom property updated.

Something along the lines of:

```
    element.addEventListener('change', () => {
    element.setAttribute('myAttrName', element.value);
});
```

The main point here is that you don't need extra elements, rather a few lines of js.

Comment: The `myAttrName` won't do anything. When the form is submitted the value will still be sent. There is no `onchange` event anyway, the event name is `change`.

Comment: Are you suggesting you can't execute javascript before submitting a form ? :D

Comment: If you're suggesting that the OP should, then half your answer is missing.

Comment: Fair enough, also my bad about the event name, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a custom attribute in your UI control Assuming you are talking about input tag then it goes like this:

```
<input type='text' id='txt' value='Display Value' data-custattr='Actual Value' />
```

while reading the value you can get the actual value like:

```
document.getElementById('txt').getAttribute('data-custattr')
```

Hope this helps.